# 'authenticationrequired' error on accessing debian repository

Tags: artifactory

I am trying to create a remote repository with Artifactory to a Debian mirror (http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de/debian/) repository. It doesn't matter which one I try, I always get the same error message:

```
Connection failed: Error 407: authenticationrequired
```

A Artifactory-wide proxy is configured and already working for NuGet, Maven and NPM package repositories.

Accessing the above mentioned repository via browser does not require any authentication.

What could be the reason for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: Only connections using HTTPS are allowed. Perhaps as for accessing the Artifactory server itself HTTPS is used already, no degredation of communication channel is allowed.